# When I use HorizontalGridView to set setFocusScrollStrategy(HorizontalGridView.FOCUS_SCROLL_PAGE), it crashes

Tags: android, television

The Java code:

```
private void initView() {
    HorizontalGridView horizontalGridView = findViewById(R.id.hg_title);
    horizontalGridView.setHorizontalSpacing(dip2px(this, 30));
    horizontalGridView.setFocusScrollStrategy(HorizontalGridView.FOCUS_SCROLL_PAGE);
    ArrayObjectAdapter arrayObjectAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new TitlePresenter());
    ItemBridgeAdapter itemBridgeAdapter = new ItemBridgeAdapter(arrayObjectAdapter);
    /*FocusHighlightHelper.setupBrowseItemFocusHighlight(itemBridgeAdapter,
            FocusHighlight.ZOOM_FACTOR_LARGE, true);*/
    horizontalGridView.setAdapter(itemBridgeAdapter);
    arrayObjectAdapter.addAll(0, titleList);

}
```

When the focus moves to the end, it crashes.
[image]